# Image link spazzes on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm putting buttons on my portfolio. I put some coding to prevent my transparent linked images from getting the highlight hover effect that my links get. Now my normal linked images spazz out on hover.

```
a:link {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover {
color: #000000;
background-color: #AF77AB;}
a:visited {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover img {
border: none !important;
display: block;}
```

How the buttons look before hover:

[image]

How the buttons look during hover:

[image]

I seem to calm the effect by putting some new coding but now the buttons aren't directly next to each other, despite the images being right next to each other and not having any breaking codes. I'd like the buttons to stay next to each other like in the first picture but now spazz out. Thank you.

```
a:link img {
border: none !important;
display: block;}
```

The linked images are in just simple coding such as:

```
<a href="http://website.com"><img src="http://image.com" border="0"><a href="http://website.com"><img src="http://image.com" border="0"></a><a href="http://website.com"><img src="http://image.com" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Please post a JSfiddle with sample image so we can work on it or post  a snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be freaking out over:

```
a:hover img {
border: none !important;
display: block;}
```

Try this:

```
a:hover img {
border: none !important;
display: inline-block;}
```